# How to clear cache after logging off in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a demoScreen.html. In this screen I am searching item and it shows list of items what i have searched. For this I am using ListItem control. I have set data-dom-cache property to true because when user navigate to any other screen it shows same list of items which he have been searched.Now there is button logOff on home search. when I turn log off and login again and goes to demoScreen.html then it shows the same list of items which he have been searched for a fraction of second and after that it empty the list.

So now what i want when user log off and login again there will be no list of items showing on screen.

Can you help me?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say. For starters, could you try show us this `demoScreen.html` file?

Comment: demoScreen.html means a page with search box and listbox

Comment: in the log off click function you have (if you don't have one then create one) empty the list ($("#mylist").empty();)